# Hundreds of branch with name origin/merge-requests/xxx

Tags: gitlab, branching-and-merging

I enable the CI flow between Gitlab to Jenkins.

When I got to Gitlab Portal, only the branchs been created by me are listed there. But when I run the CI flow, from Jenkins console output, it will list extra hundreds branchs with name origin/merge-requests/xxx, xxx is the number from 1 to 156 in my case.

Any idea why and how can I delete these branches?

Answer (score 0):

It is because Jenkins never clean local Git repo which carry a lot of stale remote branch info. These branches already been auto deleted from Git repo.

Inside Jenkins, after install Jenkins Git Plugin, we have two options to help us clean this legacy data:

Source Code Management ==> Additional Behaviors:
Wipe out repository & force clone
Prune stale remote-tracking branches